# Failed to update web app settings: Number of Web workers must be greater than zero

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I changed the tier for my function app, consumption to the app service plan. After that I got the warning `"Always on" should be enabled for your app to improve function cold start and reliability`, but when I tried to change that setting it gives me this error: `Failed to update web app settings: Number of Web workers must be greater than zero`.

Comment: Did you find the cause of your issue ? I'm having the same issue and don't understand why. I migrated two functions from a serverfarm to another, the first function was properly migrated, the other one throws this error. Both have the same configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar problem and was able to resolve it. [This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69740400/unexpected-error-updating-function-app-plan-from-consumption-to-standard-but-on) contains the solution. Bottom line: making sure numberOfWorkers on the function app settings (via REST API or CLI) is greater than 0 solved it for me.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure you are trying with ARM template or not. If you are trying with ARM template, then you can deploy function APP with the following settings.
`"numberOfWorkers": 1`, and also use the API version `"2021-03-01"`

```js
{
  "apiVersion": "2021-03-01",
  "name": "[variables('azFunctionAppName')]",
  "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites",
  "kind": "functionapp",
  "dependsOn": [
    ...
  ],
  "properties": {
    "serverFarmId": "...",
    "siteConfig": {
      "numberOfWorkers": 1,
      "alwaysOn": "parameters('alwaysOn')",
      
    }
  }
}
```